# Equivalent of CSS grid-template-columns using Qt or GTK to produce a tiled png

Tags: css, qt, layout, gtk, png

I am doing basic layout in HTML/CSS that I would like to migrate to doing without a web component, using a proper GUI library to simply render PNGs of the entire layout I am rendering currently in the browser.

I have images I am tiling in CSS using the grid-template-columns function for displaying, in this case, 2 rows of 5 images:

```
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr
}

<div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img src="mypng1.png">
    <img src="mypng2.png">
    ...
    <img src="mypng9.png">
    <img src="mypng10.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to translate this out of web/html/css and into a GUI layout that can render pngs natively on my (linux) machine.  How would I script this in either Qt or GTK, or any similar library?

Specifically, I'm looking to control:

1. Number of rows and columns
2. An ordered input list of which images
3. Space between images, potential resizing
4. Output dimensions/resolution

My example has 10 images, but I'm imagining this expanding to thousands of PNGs tiled together, so solutions like [imagemagick montage](https://codeyarns.com/2014/03/10/how-to-tile-images-using-imagemagick/) fail under RAM load before CSS does.

### Update

Thanks, very helpful comments below; I guess what I'm looking for is something ideally like:

```
$ application whatever.xml.template #or
$ application whatever.xml.template -ncol=5 myfolder/mypng* -order 1,2,3,5,4 -dim 90x90 -output master.png
```

Where whatever.xml.template might store possibly everything but the order and filename, but maybe everything I added as command line arguments.  Currently, I use my web backend to do this kind of logic and populate an HTML template.  It would be great if I could do similar templating in a non-browser-based tool to produce master.png.

Comment: `QPainter` is your friend. That is all you need, plus first grade level math skills ;)

Comment: there is **Qt Qml GridView** or other **Qml layouts**

Comment: Could you explain a bit on the end use? A photo viewer? Or a single .png generator from multiple .png files?

Comment: Thank you @theGtknerd More of the latter, actually.  I would like to make a single .png that is a collage of input pngs.  That said, I would like the ability to permute the order and structure a bit, and the number of items forming the collage could be very large.

Answer (score 1):

you can tile images in qt : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#fillMode-prop

if you want them in specific columns and rows then check [Column](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) and [Row](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qml-qtquick-row.html).
it should be simple to implement.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-repeater.html  you may want to see this too